# redux-saga yield or call() of a function returning a Promise causes other sagas to run without waiting

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

So in React I have a onClick with something like this:

```
dispatch(someAction(param1));
dispatch(secondAction(param));
```

someAction is dispatched and handled using `takeEvery` that runs a function like so:

```
function* handleSomeAction(param1) {
  // some code
  yield aFunctionThatReturnsPromise(param1);
  console.log('here1');
  // some code
}
```

and similar as up, but handling `secondAction`

```
function* handleSecondAction(param) {
  // some code
  console.log('here2');
  // some code
}
```

'here2' happens before 'here1'. Now the question is, what's the best approach block other sagas from executing. Do I have to create one saga that will launch both `handleSomeAction` and `handleSecondAction` or is there some other approach?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the full sagas code, but `yield call()` are blocking calls.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen after running the code? 'here1' is logged before 'here2'? `handleSomeAction` finishes before `handleSecondAction`? Also, can `secondAction ` be dispatched after 'here' is logged or `handleSomeAction` finishes?

Comment: @stackoverflow-newbie Yes, I am expecting 'here1' to be before 'here2'. So `handleSomeAction` should finish before `handleSecondAciton`. Do you mean like doing a `put` of the secondAction after 'here1'? Yeah it's possible, but not the best solution I think in my case, but I guess I'll have to do it if there is no better solution.

Comment: @Clarity Why do you need the whole sagas? Well yeah `yield call()` does block, but not in a case where the function is a promise or an async function from what I see.

Comment: @TheE I'm not seeing your use case for dispatching two actions at once and then expect one of the action's saga to block the other action's saga. I would suggest doing a `put` after the promise in `handleSomeAction` if possible.

Comment: @stackoverflow-newbie So I guess I'm getting things wrong? All dispatches go first and then the sagas run? I'm kinda new to redux-saga so yeah, might have got things wrong.

Comment: @TheE Yes, dispatches go first (if you're referring to the Redux store getting updated first). I'm more interested in what scenario would we have a click that would dispatch two actions but one action's saga blocks the other.

Comment: @stackoverflow-newbie So in a scenario where ALL stuff in `handleSomeAction` need to happen before `handleSecondAction`, because otherwise some data will be sent wrong. But tbh I think that overall two dispatches that depend on each other is kinda a bad approach. I quess I'll make one dispatch instead and handle `handleSomeAction` and `handleSecondAction` inside that saga. What do you think?

Comment: @TheE I think that one dispatch like you suggested is worth a try. I also think it's a little weird to have two dispatches that depend on each other.